# Complexity of appending to front of python string

Tags: python, string, time-complexity

What's the time complexity of appending to the front of a python string?

Comment: strings are immutable, there is no prepending/appending, just combining the two in an entirely new string.

Answer (score 3):

If the strings have length `m` and `n`, then appending them (it doesn't matter if it's at the beginning or at the end) will be an `O(m+n)` operation, because a new string will be created. Strings are immutable in Python, and all the chars in each of the original strings will have to be copied into the new string.

Comment: Is there a way to make a python string mutable? (Or more like a python "string" structure that is mutable?)

Comment: @hlin117 nope, but you could store all the chars into lists (which are mutable), operate on them and at the end create a string out of them, like this: `''.join(lst)`